# Inline linking to google font API

Tags: html, css, constantcontact

I am using Constant Contact and noticing that CSS seems to be nonexistent in it. I am trying to link the google font API, but only have access to the body of the HTML.

Anyone know if it is possible to link it inline?

```html
<h1 style="color: #3c3c3c; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" id="evm-lcol-title-contact"><span style="color: #0000cd;">Contact</span></h1>
```

Comment: You can insert `<link>` tag using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> [Inline Google Fonts API CSS](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-css-inline-google-fonts)

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/abcd.woff) 
    format('woff');
}
```

---

```
<h1 style="color: #3c3c3c;font-family:'Roboto'" id="evm-lcol-title-contact"><span style="color: #0000cd;">Contact</span></h1>
```